# Microsoft Graph API delta uses

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How can I retrieve the list of delta users using Microsoft Graph API for which his/her group or event data is changed? Users delta api gives the list of users for which their contact related information is changed but not when his/her skills/events/groups data is changed e.g. if few users add a new skill then in incremental mode which api I can use to get these delta users details?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get notifications about `skills`. If you try to call Graph API delta endpoint for users

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$select=skills
```

It will return the error message

> Invalid request for delta query: for this entity set, $expand/$select
> is not supported for the following properties: skills

For `events`, Graph API supports only notifications for specific user, not for all users.

```
GET /me/calendarView/delta?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
GET /users/{id}/calendarView/delta?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

For `groups`, you can call the following endpoint

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta
```

The response contains the `members@delta` property which includes the ids of member objects in the group. If the `@odata.type` is `#microsoft.graph.user` then id is the identifier of the user.

```
"members@delta": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "693acd06-2877-4339-8ade-b704261fe7a0"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "49320844-be99-4164-8167-87ff5d047ace"
    }
  ]
```

Resources:

- [event: delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
- [group: delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
- [user: delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)